# tcolorbox and pstricks are conflicting?

Tags: pstricks, tcolorbox

The following code comes from a much larger document of mine containing several pstricks and boxes generated by using `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,letterpaper,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-bar}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage{microtype}

\tcbset{noparskip}

\newcounter{mydefinition}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\themydefinition}{\unskip}

\tcbmaketheorem{definition}{Definition}{fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,arc=0mm, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black}{mydefinition}{def}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{Relative Frequency}{rf}
The \textbf{\textit{relative frequencies}} are the proportions (or percents) of the observations out of the total frequencies possible and is found using the formula
\begin{align*}
\text{relative frequency}=\frac{\text{frequency}}{\text{sum of all frequencies}}
\end{align*} 
A \textbf{\textit{relative frequency distribution}} lists each category of data
together with the relative frequency. 
\end{definition}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(9,4)
\psset{xunit=.5cm,yunit=.5cm,runit=.5cm}
\psgrid[gridlabels=0pt,subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,subgridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(0,0)(19,7)
\psaxes[Dy=2,dy=1,ymathLabel=true,xLabels={,,Brown,,,Yellow,,,Red,,,Orange,,,Blue,,,Green,,},xLabelsRot=45,xmathLabel=false]{->}(0,0)(0,0)(20,8)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

In the past, such an example would compile with pdfLaTeX with no problems, but after a recent update, it now gives errors:

```
Error: /typecheck in --div-- Operand stack: 1 1 0.0 TeXcolorgray 65781.8 Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1951 1 3 %oparray_pop 1950 1 3 %oparray_pop 1934 1 3 %oparray_pop 1820 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 5 --nostringval-- %repeat_continue --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1186/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:178/200(L)-- --dict:177/300(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Invalid argument Current file position is 256163 GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I looked at the `tcolorbox` documentation on page 258 but I can't seem to get my head around how to get the two packages working together. When I remove the definition box, it will compile without the error.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? I do have the -shell-espace option on my pdfLaTeX, if that helps.

Comment: I can confirm this error message

Comment: Why do you look on page 258?

Comment: Oops...I meant page 267. That's where I found some reference to using pstricks in the tcolorbox documentation.

Comment: I think, this is really some issue now. Since the error occurs as soon a `tcolorbox` is used, it's perhaps a bug with `tcolorbox`, but I can't explain why. On the other side: `pstricks` has been updated some days ago too.

Comment: I believe this can be closed now. After an update to tcolorbox, this example now compiles without an error.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: as the message already said: do not name your own document  `pstricks.tex`

Comment: @Herbert You're right. I think I had some tomatoes on my eyes :-)

Comment: @RobertD I made some silly error with my first try to compile your example. But now, it does without problems. As you have suggested, I will vote to close this questions since updating `tcolorbox` and/or `pstricks` seems to solve the matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can be solved by updating the related packages. This was a suggestion by the OP.